# avoid deletion of singleton in multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a generic singleton class  in C++ which works   in single threaded but since now I am going to multithreaded environment I want to make sure that singleton work there and one thing which is crashing is multiple threads are trying to call delete on that single pointer. Is there a way without use of locks to avoid this error.

```
class singleton
{
public : 
    static singleton* getinstance();
private :
    singleton();
    singleton(const singleton& that);
    singleton& operator=(const singleton& that);
    static singleton* ptr;
};
```

Comment: What's in `getinstance` and where is the `delete` which is causing you trouble? Although, strictly, we can answer this by providing the standard idiom for extern globals, your question is missing most of the important parts.

Comment: Also, how is this actually used to produce an object? I would expect to see a `template` or something… this appears to be a base class that can only produce one object of any derived class.

Comment: I have ommited most of the internals as I just want to know how to use singleton in multithreaded environment and best way to synchronise access. just like you use Enums in java instead of normal singleton class.

Comment: But what you've posted raises more questions than answers. If you just asked "how to make a global variable" that would be one thing, but now it looks like you have some strange requirements we can't see.

Comment: If you synchronise it, it will end up being slower than single threaded code. Either remove the singleton, or stick with singlethreaded if you want fast code.

Comment: @doctorlove Huh? You seem to be over-generalizing something. Shared globals need to be locked according to their own specific semantics. If there's a performance issue you need to adjust the semantics, not remove threading/locking.

Comment: @doctorlove It's not even specific to globals, exactly the same situation for any object used to communicate between threads.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I know people writing operating systems need to use low level things like locks, but there are high level or functional ways of doing things. See here http://www.russel.org.uk/Presentations/JAXLondon2012_2012-10-16_itsAllAboutProcessesCommunicating.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better this way. Nothing to complain about. Cheers!

Comment: To cover the multithreading aspect, the system adds a lock around the object initialization so the first thread to access the object is the one to initialize it. To clarify the deletion aspect, static objects are deleted while the program terminates, in the opposite order of their construction.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, that's another subject. The point here is that if it is a singleton, then there is no need for deletion. 'static' with a 'reference' will do the job.

Comment: Well, tl;dr: the specific questions he asked are "already taken care of."

Comment: This is only true in C++11.  Previously, it was implementation defined, and you would usually need a lock.  In a multithreaded environment, it's probably better to use the pointer, and make sure that it is set before starting any threads, so that you can be sure of avoiding the lock.

Comment: What exactly is only true in C++11?

Comment: @user1764961: Before C++11, the construction wasn't guaranteed to be thread-safe, since there was no concept of threading in the language. These days, this code is required to be thread-safe; this is typically achieved by adding an invisible lock, so it's debatable whether this solution meets the "without use of locks" requirement.

Comment: These days it is impossible to offer an answer to question, because every developer is also a lawyer. Don't worry, I will delete this one.

Answer (score 1):

Where's it being deleted?  A singleton is usually never deleted;
if you want it destructed (which you usually don't), you use the
Meyers idiom; otherwise, you allocate it once, and never delete
it.

The issue of threading is more delicate.  The simplest solution
is usually to ensure that the `instance` function is called at
least once before threading starts, usually as the result of the
initialization of a static variable.  Once the pointer is
non-null, it never changes, so there's no issue with regards to
threading.  (But this has nothing to do with deleting anything.)